# Javascript Text from link to text box

Tags: javascript, html, function, hyperlink

I have a hyperlink and an image, I want to add the text of the link on the text box when clicking on it.

I have this now: but i can't figure out how to get the name in the textbox.

```
<script language="javascript">
<!--
function insertText()
{   
    var url;
    document.meldformulier.melding.value = url;
}
//-->
</script>

<a id="melding" onClick="insertText()"; href="javascript:void;">Zwaar onweer</a>

<input id="melding" name="melding" type="text" size="35" readonly="readonly" />
```

The result is undefined. So as example. The link text is "zwaar onweer". When clicking on the hyperlink of this text, the TEXT "zwaar onweer" should appear in the textbox.

Can someone help me ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was scratching my head for a couple of minutes wondering why a simple answer here wasn't working for me. Turns out that since you had repeated IDs in your link and input that it was the source of my error.

Issues:

1. You duplicated IDs. That's a no-no.
2. Your `url` variable has no meaning. Get rid of it.

Pass a reference to your link to the function like this, using `this`:

```
<a onClick="insertText(this)" href="javascript:void(0)">Zwaar onweer</a>
```

And change your function to:

```
function insertText(txt) {
    document.getElementById('melding').value = txt.innerHTML;
}
```

Within the function, use the txt argument to reference the anchor that's being passed in, and the `innerHTML` property to get the text and place it in the input.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/fhjzdj4z/)**

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following changes in your code.

**Javascript**

```
 function insertText(obj) 
{
    document.getElementById('txtmelding').value = obj.innerText;
 }
```

**HTML Code**

```
 <a id="melding" onclick="insertText(this)" href="javascript:void;">Zwaar onweer</a>
<input id="txtmelding" name="txtmelding" type="text" size="35" readonly="readonly" />
```

Answer (score 0):

What about just assigning a value to the input box. You can make it match the id of your link and take the text from that using jquery.

```
function insertText()
{   
var url = $('#melding').text();
    $('input[name="melding"]').val(url);
}
```

Should work, here is a [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u47fyw8t/)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly It is `document.getElementById` secondly there must be

> no duplicate ID's

and the changes are

```js
function insertText(txt) {
    document.getElementById('melding').value = txt.innerHTML;
}
```

```html
<a onClick="insertText(this)" href="javascript:void(0)">Zwaar onweer</a>

<input id="melding" name="melding" type="text" size="35" readonly="readonly" />
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to store the value of the link in a variable first. Also, you need different id's for your elements. Suppose your id for hyperlink is "a" and your id for textbox is "tb". Then you will have

```
function insertText()
{   
  var url= document.getElementById("a").value;
  var textboxValue= document.getElementById("tb");
  textboxValue.value= url;
}
```